# when i have add to product error display ReferenceError: Uploader is not defined?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, product-images, image-upload, magento-1.5.1

[image]

When click on browse Button pop up not open and Show me error in console.

Comment: Is js merged for admin?

Comment: No i have check.

Comment: https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader - You can use Dull Uploader if issue not resolved. It is not using flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching i found that magento 1.9.3.0 they remove the flash uploader so js file need to run uploader add these file in head

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</file></action>
            <action method="addJs"><file>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</file></action>
</reference>
```